# script de compras, no arquivo txt o nome dos objetos das compras, não ficam abaixo um do outro

Tags: python

```
print('Programa de controle: Lista de compras 1.0')

numero_compras = input('Numero de itens: ')
lista_compras = []

i = 1
while i <= int(numero_compras):
    nome_compras = input('Preencha com o nome da compra #' + str(i) + ': ')
    lista_compras.append(nome_compras)
    i += 1
print('\n')
print('Foi adicionado',numero_compras,"Itens para sua compra.")
# noinspection PyInterpreter
print('\nLista de Compras: ')
for compras in lista_compras:
    print(compras)


arquivo = open('lista01.txt', 'w')
arquivo.write('Sua lista: \n')
arquivo.writelines(lista_compras)
with open('lista01.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        print(linha.rstrip())
```

Comment: As suas strings não possuem a quebra de linha no final.

Comment: essa aqui print(linha.rstrip())?

Comment: ou todas as outras strings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executei mudanças simples, no `append` acrescentei o caractere de escape para quebra de linha e no `print` que há dentro da estrutura de repetição substitui a variável por **nome_compras**.

Segue o código alterado:

```
print('Programa de controle: Lista de compras 1.0')

numero_compras = input('Numero de itens: ')
lista_compras = []

i = 1
while i <= int(numero_compras):
    nome_compras = input('Preencha com o nome da compra #' + str(i) + ': ')
    lista_compras.append(nome_compras+'\n')
    i += 1
print('\n')
print('Foi adicionado',numero_compras,"Itens para sua compra.")
# noinspection PyInterpreter
print('\nLista de Compras: ')
for compras in lista_compras:
    print(nome_compras)


arquivo = open('lista01.txt', 'w')
arquivo.write('Sua lista: \n')
arquivo.writelines(lista_compras)
with open('lista01.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        print(linha.rstrip())
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MistyPlumpAssembler)

Comment: brother, obrigado mesmo, e eu aqui quebrando a cabeça...

Comment: sou novo, novo em parte, parei de programar tem uns anos, estudei mecatrônica, desistir para trabalhar e ajudar em casa, agora voltei a estudar programação.

Comment: @MichaelOliver só uma sugestão, evite comentários como "valeu", "obrigado", o melhor agradecimento é você marcar a resposta como útil, clicando na seta, e/ou se resolveu seu problema totalmente, marque a resposta como aceita, no visto :D